# Quasiparticle in QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I'm reading the book QFT by Blundell and I'd like to clarify some concepts regarding interacting theory in the context of quasiparticles.

To create a particle with momentum $\textbf{p}$, we can use the creation operator $a^\dagger_p$ on the "free" ground state $|{0}\rangle$. However, for the interacting theory the ground state is given by $|\Omega\rangle$. One of the keypoints is to ask if there is a corresponding operator $q^\dagger_p$ in the interacting theory that can create a single particle with the same momentum $\textbf{p}$ from $|\Omega\rangle$. Unfortunately, we do not know anything about $q^\dagger_p$. However, since we know about $a^\dagger_p$, we ask the question what happens when we use this operator on the interacting ground state $|\Omega\rangle$.

$\textbf{Question 1.}$ Why does $a^\dagger_p$ create a superposition of states when acted on $|\Omega\rangle$?

$\textbf{Question 2.}$ Can anyone explain more about the first three paragraphs on p. 277? First of all, I know that a state $|{\textbf{p}_\lambda}\rangle$ will be a sharp wave packet with infinitesimal width in the momentum space but since we can only create it approximately the wave packet will have a finite width $\Gamma_p$. However, the details of the succeeding quantities discussed are lacking, i.e. $E+i\Gamma_p$, $(2\Gamma_p)^{-1}$, etc. I'm not sure where they came from or how to derive them or at least a "passing" derivation even from physical arguments (I don't have to know every detail of the derivation here and there but at least to know where those parts originated).

[image]